# NameError: name "something" is not defined - Web App using Angular JS and Python

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, python-2.7, bottle

I am developing a web application using Python and Angular JS. I am using the bottle python framework for my web server.

My files are as below:

app.py

```
import json
import os
from bottle import run, route, template, static_file, request, redirect, get, post
import json
#import MySQLdb

#######################
# Static file servers #
#######################

ROOTPATH = ''

@route('/assets/<filepath:path>')
def serve_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='static/')


##############
#  Handlers  #
##############

@route('/')
def root():
    return template('index.html')

def main():
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=55500, debug=True, reloader=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="astra">
    <head>
        <title> ASTRA DB </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Test Case ID </th>
                    <th> Test Case Description </th>
                    <th> Tester Assigned </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="testCase in testDB">
                    <td>{{ testCase.testCaseID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ testCase.testCaseDesc }}</td>
                    <td>{{ testCase.tester}}
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        angular.module('astra', [])
               .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.testDB = [
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 1,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To create a test case table",
                        "tester" : "Veeresh A"
                    },
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 2,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To go to wonder la",
                        "tester" : "Veeresh A"
                    },
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 3,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "Never take a Meru Cab",
                        "tester" : "Pallavi Bansod"
                    },
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 4,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To kill a mocking bird",
                        "tester" : "pallavi bansod"
                    },
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 5,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To avoid a farha khan movie",
                        "tester" : "Satyajit Patnaik"
                    },
                    {
                        "testCaseID" : 6,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To talk to the customer care",
                        "tester" : "Mummana Santhoshi"
                    },{
                        "testCaseID" : 7,
                        "testCaseDesc" : "To be late to wherever you go",
                        "tester" : "Deepa Javoor"
                    }
                ];



               }]);

    </script>
</html>
```

On running `python app.py` from the command prompt, the server starts, but when I hit the "localhost:55500" address on a browser, it throws the following errors.

```
> $ python app.py Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using
> WSGIRefServer())... Listening on http://0.0.0.0:55500/ Hit Ctrl-C to
> quit.
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "e:\git\pychip\bottle.py",
> line 861, in _handle
>     return route.call(**args)   File "e:\git\pychip\bottle.py", line 1741, in wrapper
>     rv = callback(*a, **ka)   File "app.py", line 45, in root
>     return template('index.html')   File "e:\git\pychip\bottle.py", line 3494, in template
>     return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)   File "e:\git\pychip\bottle.py", line 3320, in render
>     self.execute(stdout, env)   File "e:\git\pychip\bottle.py", line 3307, in execute
>     eval(self.co, env)   File "e:\git\pychip\views\index.html", line 15, in <module>
>     <td>{{ testCase.testCaseID }}</td> NameError: name 'testCase' is not defined
> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2015 09:50:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1719
> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2015 09:50:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 749
```

I am getting the nameerror exception. Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: You are rendering index.html as a template, bottle and angular templating syntax is similar `{{ }}`. Bottle is looking for variable `testCase` which you mean to use with angular instead. Serve index.html as a static file or just use a simple webserver.

Comment: `something` is what? can you give me a exact error?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I just used something for generic means. In my example, something is equal to the variable name testCase. U can refer the angular code above.

Comment: @kedar How can I do that? Can you be specific?

Comment: I am not familiar with bottle so I can't say much, but if you just want to serve HTML pages, no need to use bottle. Run (from the command line) `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8018` in the directory with index.html and go to `http://localhost:8018/index.html` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks Kedar! I was able to resolve it. U were right. I had to use a python method serving static file instead. Great! thanks. I will take that advice of using SimpleHTTPServer in consideration too. Bottle helps me in routing though, so I need to stick with bottle python.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER to my problem is:

Instead of doing the following

```
@route('/')
def root():
    return template('index.html')
```

Do this:

```
@route('/')
def root():
    return static_file('index.html', root="views/")
```

As kedar said it rightly, bottle and angular have a similar templating syntax. So I need to use the HTML pages as static files so that angular templating is adhered here.